# Recommendations for future-facing (fully cloud-based) Identity and EMM/UEM Solutions

Tags: g-suite, entra-id, identity-management, endpoint, microsoft-intune

I have recently started consulting for a tech startup of about 60 users that has grown, and is looking to expand, quickly.
Due to the fast growth, and lack of formal IT advice up until now, they are badly in need of solutions around Identity and Endpoint management in particular, in order to at least meet basic cyber-security requirements.
They do not currently have any on-premises servers - they are using exclusively cloud-based services.  There are a mix of Windows, Mac & Linux systems.
They currently use Office 365, although it's not entirely engrained in the culture - they toyed with switching to G Suite a while back (which would probably suit the culture better) but are making do by using numerous different non-Microsoft packages.

It seems like there are a few options at this stage, in order to gain control of the security of the devices on the network and manage users' online identities:

- Azure AD + Intune
- G Suite + ?UEM?

I would be very interested to hear about solutions that people have rolled out/are planning for full EMM/UEM with no on-premises AD.  What is the most user-friendly, modern and flexible approach?

Answer (score 0):

I am having several organizations with 100+ users/devices in cloud-only (modern) environment with Microsoft 365 and Azure solutions, without any server or virtual machine (on-prem or cloud).

Since your scenario is already using Office 365, then Azure AD exists and in default version is a free tier which is enough. This also supports Azure AD Device joined devices.
If you need more control then purchase Microsoft Intune subscription for additional device configuration (including Windows, macOS, Android, iOS...)